# Drupal 7 selection rules based on comments

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, panels

I want to create panel view based on comment.
I there is any comment i want to disable comment for, and when there are no comment related to node i want to display comment form.

I want to do it via selection rules but I don't see any selection rules regarding to comments.
I also try php visibility rule

```
if(%node:comment-count-new ==0)return false;
```

Still not working any one can help ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that since you're writing php, you could just find out the count yourself, ex. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8582/how-to-show-node-comment-count-in-node-tpl

And if you want to find out the parameter from URL, ex. the current node id, use arg(1).